# Telegram bot using Telegraf in Node.js question

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegraf

I'm still pretty new to Node.js,
I'm trying to make a bot that prompts the user to search a word and then looks in a MySQL db for matching rows.
The search process should be divided in 2 steps:

1. User is asked to chose an option via inline keyboard, only then;
2. User is asked to write the word to search for.

Bot should search database in the table selected by option in step 1 for the word entered in step 2 and retrive the row.
Also the bot should handle multiple users.
I've tried using Wizards but as there isn't a lot of documentation I'm not able to handle inline keyboard callbacks.
Sql part isn't much of a problem, I'm using npm "mysql".

Here's the code I've come up with:

```
const { Telegraf } = require('telegraf');
const session = require('telegraf/session');
const Stage = require('telegraf/stage');
const WizardScene = require('telegraf/scenes/wizard');
const bot = new Telegraf('token-here');

bot.start( (ctx) => {
    ctx.reply('Bot started!');
})

const menuKeyboard = [
    [
        {text: 'OPT1', callback_data: 'CB_OPT1'},
        {text: 'OPT2', callback_data: 'CB_OPT2'},
        {text: 'OPT3', callback_data: 'CB_OPT3'}
    ],
    [
        {text: 'OPT4', callback_data: 'CB_OPT4'},
        {text: 'OPT5', callback_data: 'CB_OPT5'},
        {text: 'OPT6', callback_data: 'CB_OPT6'}
    ]
]

bot.action(['CB_OPT1', 'CB_OPT2', 'CB_OPT3', 'CB_OPT4', 'CB_OPT5', 'CB_OPT6'], (ctx) => {
    ctx.deleteMessage();
    ctx.reply(`Insert search term:`);
    return ctx.wizard.steps[1](ctx); //Re-enters wizard?
})

//Wizzard setup
const superWizard = new WizardScene('super-wizard',
    //Step 1 - Ask option
    ctx => {
        ctx.reply("Select an option:", {
            reply_markup: {
                inline_keyboard: menuKeyboard
            }
        });
        ctx.wizard.state.data = {};
        return ctx.wizard.next();
        //Callback calls bot.action above
    },

    ctx => {
        ctx.deleteMessage();
        ctx.wizard.state.data.option = ctx.message.text;
    }
);

const stage = new Stage([superWizard]);

bot.use(session());
bot.use(stage.middleware());

bot.command('search', (ctx) => {
    //ctx.scene.enter('super-wizard');
    ctx.reply("Select an option:", {
        reply_markup: {
            inline_keyboard: menuKeyboard
        }
    });
})

bot.launch();
```

Is using wizards the best approach?
Thanks!, I've just started out :)